# Axios fetch data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am having trouble fetching data from my API and displaying it on my page. Sometimes the data is defined and I have no issue, but sometimes I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'calls' of undefined". I am not sure if there is an issue with my useEffect or what is happening, I thought that this would wait for the data to be pulled before displaying it. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import AuthService from "../../services/auth.service";
import axios from 'axios';
import _, { map } from 'underscore';


const LineChart = () => {
  const currentUser = AuthService.getCurrentUser();
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  const authAxios = axios.create({
    baseURL: `http://localhost:3000`,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    }
  });

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await authAxios.get('/call/' + currentUser.id);
      setData(result.data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [setData]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="relative bg-white p-6 rounded-lg shadow-lg">
        <div className="relative bg-blueGray-100">
          <h6 className="uppercase mb-1 text-xl font-semibold">
            Filler Words Used Per Call
          </h6>
          <Line
            data={{
              labels: _.range(1, Object.keys(data.calls).length + 1),
              datasets: [
                {
                  label: "Phone Calls",
                  fill: false,
                  lineTension: 0.5,
                  backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                  borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
                  borderWidth: 2,
                  data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56],
                }
              ]
            }}
            options={{
              title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Phone Calls",
                fontSize: 20,
              },
              legend: {
                display: true,
                position: "right",
              },
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
};
export default LineChart;
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `data` not `setData` => `useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [data]);`

Comment: I still have the same issue when I change it.

Comment: `labels: _.range(1, Object.keys(data.calls).length + 1),` line is failing at initial loading time as axios is async. You can keep a check and return only when data is available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render the `Line` component conditionally: `{data && <Line data={...} />}`

Unrelated issue: You still should remove the `setData` from `useEffect` dependancy array, like other people suggested, but it won't address your missing data issue. You only want to fetch data once on mount, so leave the dependancy array empty.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether `setData` is in the dependency array or not. Either way it will only fetch once.

Comment: That's good to know, but it can't possibly be a good reason to keep it there.

Comment: Thank you for the help! My issue is resolved now!

Answer (score 0):

You do still need to remove the dependency of `useEffect`. The other problem is that `data` is `undefined`, for some reason. The `<Line>` component is probably rendering before `data` has been populated.

Add conditional rendering for `<Line>` such as `{data && <Line data={...}>...</Line>}`. Then the `Line` component will only be rendered when `data` has a value.

Comment: If you initialise `data` to an empty array, `data && <Line ... />` would evaluate to `true`. You'd want to check `data.length` in this case.

Comment: Ah, oops. I got things mixed up and was thinking `data` was an array. Good catch, thanks.